# Conditional Statement for Array: Need to Store Values Not Equal to Value at Index in C

Tags: c, arrays, conditional-statements

I have an integer pointer array b_members that contains something like the following values:

```
1 2 4
```

I want to find the values of b_members that are not equal to a specific value inside a loop and store them in another integer pointer array i_p.

For example, inside my loop at index 0 I want to find and store the two values in b_members not equal to 1, (i.e. 2 and 4). So for the first iteration

```
ip = 2 4
```

In the second iteration I want to store 1 and 4 in ip so

```
ip = 1 4
```

And in the third iteration I want to store 1 and 2 in ip so

```
ip = 1 2
```

I can do this in Matlab using the code below but I want to be able to do this in C.

```
b_members = [1 2 4];
for i = b_members
    ip = b_members(b_members ~=i);
end
```

Heres what I have in C so far:

```
int *b_members;
int *i_p;

b_members = Get_b_members(B,j); // fills b_members with array like [1 2 4]

for(int i=0;i<B->Columns;++i){ // going through all of b_members
    printf("%d ",b_members[i]);
    // Finding b_members not equal to b_members[i]
    for(int i2=0;i2<B->Columns;++i2){
        if (b_members[i2] != b_members[i])
            i_p = &b_members[i2];
            }
} // End b_members for loop
```

I can't seem to get it to work the right way, i_p just keeps getting longer as the loop progresses and I only want it to contain the two integers at a time. Is there a way to do this like the Matlab code I provided above? Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Using Saurav Sahu's suggestion this worked:

```
        int **i_p = (int **)malloc(B->Columns * sizeof(int*));
        int tmp;
        for(int i=0;i<B->Columns;i++)
        {
            // Need to find b_members excluding b_members(i)
            i_p[i] = (int *)malloc((B->Columns-1) * sizeof(int));
            int idx = 0;
            for(int jj=0;jj<=B->Columns;jj++)
            {
                if(i==jj) continue;
                if(b_members[i] != b_members[jj])
                {
                    i_p[i][idx++] = b_members[jj];
                }
            }
            tmp = i;
        }

        for(int ii=0;ii<=tmp;++ii)
        {
            printf("\ti_p[%d] = ",ii);
            for(int it=0;it<(B->Columns)-1;++it)
            {
                printf("%d ",i_p[ii][it]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
```

Comment: How are you going to handle duplicate values in input array? Will you still add them?

Comment: I dont think the duplicate values matter, if b_members = [1 6 6], the first iteration would give i_p = [6 6], second would give i_p = [1 6], and third would give i_p = [1 6].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pointer of integer pointers like [this](http://ideone.com/7uXrYG). Assign enough size to each integer pointers to store `array_size-1` integers.

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 4};
int aSize = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
int **b = (int **)malloc(aSize * sizeof(int*));;
for(int i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
     b[i] = (int *)malloc((aSize-1) * sizeof(int));
     int idx = 0;
     for(int j = 0; j < aSize; j++){
        if(i == j) continue;
        if(a[i] != a[j]) {
            b[i][idx++] = a[j];
        }
     }
}
```

It works perfectly.